# ubuntu 20.04 - trouble updating software

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, software-update

When I try to run the software updater on Ubuntu 20.04, the text in the updater window disappears and the empty window sits there doing nothing. I tried restarting the computer with no change. The updater was working fine until the last week or two.

Comment: What is the output if you open a terminal and execute "sudo apt update;sudo apt upgrade" ?

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you. I'll have to remember that.